# Network Communication - Some Information does not reach the Server

Tags: delphi, chat, delphi-6

I have a little problem with a program I'm writing at the moment.

First let me explain what it should achieve.

It is very similar to a chat-program, so it basicially has an information-class (I called it Packet) which stores data about some things, that happen on the client-window. The Program itself consists of two diffrent client-windows and a server-window. (And one Window to open up each of those, but thats not important now.)

So the client changes some things on his Window and presses send.

Then my Packet will store all this information. It consists of a Nickname, a Text, some diffrent number-values (basicially Dice-Roll Results) and a 'Kind'-Variable.

There are three diffrent kinds of messages, this 'Packet' is capable of sending.

1. A normal text message (Works perfectly.)
2. A Dice-Message, consisting of 3 dice-results, a difficulty-value and a talent-value.
3. Another Dice-Message, this time only consisting of one dice-result.

Whenever a Message is sent (and thus received by the server) the program reads out, what kind of message it is (via the kind-variable) and initiates different steps to handle the message, according to what it is.

The Chat-Message is simply displayed in chat and sent to each client to be displayed there too. This works without any bugs or something.

The Dice-Messages both have a special shape to show up.
Its basicially a Chat-Message generated in this shape to show if the dice-roll was successful or not.

---

Now comes my problem:

I tested the program in a LAN-Version (using my locale-IP) and it worked perfectly. No problems, no bugs.

But now I asked a friend to help me testing it via internet.
Portforwarding worked, the clients are able to connect.

Now for the sending of messages.
Chatmessage: Works fine
Dice1-Message: Only Nickname and two dice-results are sent. The third dice-result does not show up and every other information simply leaves a blank space there, where it should appear.
Same goes for the second dice-message. It Shows only the dice-result and the nickname, but not any other information.

If it helps to know, the program is written with Delphi 6.0 (Yes, a bit old, but im used to this program and I'm not that good with programming yet.. so I use it for learning the basics and for writing my first bigger programs, like that one.)

The Packet itself is defined like this:

```
type
TPacket  = Record
  Nickname : string[255];
  Text     : string[255];
  OtherInfo: VarType;
end;
```

etc.
The Message then refers to the information like this:

```
ServerSocket.Socket.ReceiveBuf (Packet, SizeOf(Packet));

MemMessage.Lines.Add(Packet.Nickname + 'succeeded his dice roll for ' + Packet.Talent + 'Restofmessage ' + Packet.OtherInformation)
```

So.. Thats how it is. I hope anyone out there knows whats the problem (or better whats the problem-causing difference between LAN and Internet in this case) and knows of a way to help me fix this.

Thanks in Advance~

PS: The server simply takes the Information, displays it the same way, any client does and then sends it directly to each client, which receives and displays it.. Just in case this might be important.

---

**Edit:**

Hm I thought that the information was good as it was, because the 'other informations' arent really different.

But okay~ More details :)

The 'other Informations' all have the type string[255], anyways one of them is a boolean.

The *Dice1*-Type uses the following:

Nickname, Result1, Result2, Result3, Difficulty, Skillpoints, Talent (Just the name of the talent, which the dice roll tests success or fail on) and a boolean called 'Success'.

*Dice2* uses:

Nickname, Result, Difficulty, Talent (Name of the talent. Dont mistake for the value^^), TalentPoints (Basicially the value of the Talent minus the Difficulty of the dice-roll) and also the boolean 'Success' as well as a string[255] called 'Kind'. Kind's Function is explained above.

As for the protocol, I dont use any special one, I think..

I simply send the whole class TPacket via SendBuf and ReceiveBuf.
Im quite new to programming, so I'm sorry that I cannot give you much more information than that :/

Let me give you the code for the procedure, the server uses for receiving and redirecting the TPacket.

I hope I don't make any mistakes, because I write the program on german, so I have to translate it now..^^

```
procedure TFormServer.ServerSocketClientRead (Sender:TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
Message : TPacket;
i       : ShortInt;
begin
  {receive Message}
 Socket.ReceiveBuf (Message, SizeOf(Message))

{checking, what kind the message is of}
   if Message.Kind = 'Chat' then begin
     MemMessage.Lines.Add ('By' + Message.Nickname + ': ' + Message.Text);

     {Redirecting to other clients}
    with ServerSocket.Socket do begin
      for i := 0 to ActiveConnections -1 do
         Connections[I].SendBuf(Message, SizeOf(Message))
    end;
   end;


   if Message.Kind = 'DiceRoll_1' then begin
     if Message.Success = true
        then MemMessage.Lines.Add (Message.Nickname + ' succeeded his Dice Roll for ' + Message.Talent + ' (Difficulty: ' + Message.Difficulty + ') with the results: (' + Message.Result1 + '/' + Message.Result2 + '/' + Message.Result3 + '), Skill lvl: ' + Message.Skillpoints);

//The Message should look like that
{Dummy succeeded his Dice Roll for climbing (Difficulty: 4) with the results: (12/14/13), Skill lvl: 8}

//For Comparison, the buggy message looks like that
{Dummy succeeded his Dice Roll for  (Difficulty:  ) with the results: (12/14/ ), Skill lvl:  }
        else {The same as when it succeeded, just saying it did 'not' succeed..}


     {redirection}
    with ServerSocket.Socket do begin
      for i := 0 to ActiveConnections -1 do
         Connections[i].SendBuf (Message, SizeOf(Message))
    end;

  end; {if kind = DiceRoll_1}

{Same goes for the DiceRoll_2 now. This time it uses: Message.Nickname, Message.Talent, Message.Difficulty, Message.Result, Message.TalentPoints, Message.Success}
```

Now again the whole declaration of my TPacket.. May be important

```
type    TPacket = Result
  Kind        : string[255];
  Nickname    : string[255];
  Text        : string[255];
  Result      : string[255];
  Result1     : string[255];
  Result2     : string[255];
  Result3     : string[255];
  Difficulty  : string[255];
  Talent      : string[255];
  Skillpoints : string[255];
  TalentPoints: string[255];
  Succeed     : boolean;
end;
```

I hope that made it more understandable..
I'm not that good at explaining, i suppose :/

However, thanks for welcoming me here, I hope I'm no bother for you guys and can help in one or another case too!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suspect the `OtherInfo` and the overall `SizeOf(Packet)` here (what might be resolved by packed record alignment, what is just a guess right now). But could you show us at least what the `OtherInfo` may contain and add details like what library (I guess Indy) and what protocol are you using ? I think the description of how your program works is less useful than these details here. Anyway, are you sure the data didn't reached server ? Have you tried to use tools like Wireshark or similar ?

Comment: Your "Message refers to" code doesn't match the information you gave us for `TPacket`. How are we supposed to help you figure out the problem when you don't provide the necessary information? :) Please edit your question, remove some of the long descriptive text, and update the part that matters with details that go together? It will greatly improve your chances of getting help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. if it's the component I'm thinking of, it's not a lock that the ClientRead event is fired with a complete message full of data.

If this is the case, you need a protocol on top of TCP to allow the transfer of messages.  TCP on its own cannot transfer messages, only byte streams.

TCustomWinSocket docs, (my italics):

'Use ReceiveBuf to read from the socket connection in the OnSocketEvent event handler of a Windows socket object or in the OnRead or OnClientRead event handler of a socket component.

**ReceiveBuf returns the number of bytes actually read** (*which may be less than the number requested in the call*).

If no bytes are read, ReceiveBuf returns –1.'

So, your cunning plan of just declaring oversize buffers and always transferring the lot in an attempt to avoid parsing the received data has not worked.

You need to do it correctly.  Design a protocol that will work whether the ClientRead() event fires with a whole message, partial message, combined messages or just lots of times with one byte each time.  My preferred design is to use a 'PDU' class with a 'byteLoad(thischar:char):boolean;' method that uses an internal state-machine to handle the protocol, loads up fields with the corect data and only returns true when a complete message has been assembled.  In every ClientRead call, I iterate every received byte and call 'byteLoad' until it returns true, then handle the PDU, (maybe by queueing it off somewhere), create another PDU and start loading that up.

Note that, since you are using the asynchronous, non-threaded TServerSocket choice, any such client-specific data like PDU instances or any other data that must be preserved across ClientRead calls must be stored as fields of the TCustomWinSocket instance that is passed in.  This means either a TCustomWinSocket descendant to hold this data, or using the 'data' property of the base TCustomWinSocket to hold another object or record.  That stuff is usually created/initialized/loaded in the OnConnected event.  Beware of behaviour of TCustomWinSocket on disconnect - I've got a funny feeling that it tries to free any non-nil pointer in the data field - something you may not want.

Answer (score 0):

Which protocol are you using?

If this is UDP, then those issues are "by design" of this protocol.

Lacking reliability, UDP applications must generally be willing to accept some loss, errors or duplication.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Over a local network, it works without issue, since conditions are optimal.

But over then Internet, some packets are lost.

If you want the data to be routed, you'll either to add an acknowledge + resend mechanism in your applications over UDP (see the TFTP protocol for a naive one), or use a more advanced protocol, like TCP, which will retry to send the data in case of packet loss - but will have a bigger overhead.

For plain chat program, using TCP (even with a HTTP layout if necessary - this is more firewall friendly), does make sense; even if this protocol is not duplex, you can pull data on a regular period (e.g. 1 second), to ask a server for pending messages.

By the way, using `string[255]` is a bit rude for an application layer. It could make sense to use a #13#10 (line feed) terminated text, or even a #0 terminated text. Most of your packet will be unused during chat, and you won't be able to use more than 255 characters in your text. Or rely on a standard format, like XML or JSON for your message layout.

Comment: I actually do not know wheter I'm using UDP, TCP or even another protocol.. Maybe from the edited information, I added its clear, what one I use. As far as I can guess by what you said it should be UDP. (No pressing enter possible in comments.. yay~) However, the interesting thing is, that its always the same information missing. To me (and what I think, packet loss is), it should lose random information and not a fixed kind of information.. I suppose i just do not sufficiently understand network communication yet...

Comment: It will depend on how you create your socket. I guess this is UDP. For your purpose, you'd better rely on TCP or HTTP, with a JSON format for your message.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it's TCP.  Looks like a TServerSocket component.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez `TCP or HTTP`? I don't know what this means ;)